# Reading in column issue

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am running into a slight problem when running my VBA code. I am trying to retrieve and check the information in a specified column in excel. It will run 16 times retrieving the information until the 17 time where it doesn't even give me the whats in the column from the workbook. Can you please help or guide me to the solution?

```
  Dim CheckingWhatsInCell As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer


  Dim ToWorkbook As Workbook



  ThisWorkbook.Activate


  For i = 1 To 20
    CheckingWhatsInCell = Trim(Range("K" & i).Value)
   If CheckingWhatsInCell = "Albuquerque  NM" Then
       Set ToWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mgonza-c\Documents\TerritoryAlbuquerqueNM.xlsx")
       For j = 1 To 139
       ToWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j).Value
       Next j
    End If

  Next i
  ToWorkbook.Save
  ToWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code that would cause an error. It is likely that you have invalid data in K17 that is causing the error.

Comment: Hey Pynner! Thanks for your reply. What do you mean invalid data? Like cell formatting?

Comment: Would cell K17 have an error like #DIV!0 or #N/A or #VALUE etc?
For i = 17, what is the vlaue of CheckingWhatsIncell ?

Comment: Hi Julien, Thanks for replying. The value for i = 17 in the workbook is Albuquerque  NM but when it reads in its " " (empty)

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckingWhatsInCell = Trim(Range("K" & i).Value)
```

This code will be looking in ThisWorkbook, which is Active, and in whichever Sheet was last active. Perhaps it's looking in the wrong sheet. The situation will also change when the other workbook is opened, making it active.

Then, as Julien suggests, there may be an *odd* value in K17.

Also note that you are attempting to Save and Close ToWorkbook even though it may never be assigned to a Workbook.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought opening it every time `Albuquerque  NM` is found would help either